# Is it possible to prevent the component from re-rendering without creating a new hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications, infinite-scroll

**EDIT: Solved it few hours later and here's how in case someone comes to this:**
Re-rendering is not an issue, the whole thing was in the way I display the articles inside the feed. The proper way is to have a component which handles the listing of articles like this:

```
....
   const cardItems = (
    <>
      <div className="article-card__title">
        <h2>{article.title}</h2>
      </div>

      <img
        src={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${article.img}`}
        alt=""
        className="article-card__img"
      />
      <div className="article-card__category">{article.category}</div>
      <div className="article-card__content">
        <p>{article.content}</p>
      </div>
      <div className="article-card__date">{articleDate}</div>
    </>
  );


  const content = ref ? (
    <div className="article-card" ref={ref}>
      {cardItems}
    </div>
  ) : (
    <div className="article-card">{cardItems}</div>
  );
  return content;
});
```

And render it that way:

```
const Feed = () => {
  const {
    fetchNextPage,
    hasNextPage,
    isFetchingNextPage,
    data,
    status,
    error,
  } = useArticlesContext();

  const intObserver = useRef();
  const lastPostRef = useCallback(
    (post) => {
      if (isFetchingNextPage) return;
      if (intObserver.current) intObserver.current.disconnect();

      intObserver.current = new IntersectionObserver((posts) => {
        if (posts[0].isIntersecting && hasNextPage) {
          console.log('We are near the last post');
          fetchNextPage();
        }
      });

      if (post) intObserver.current.observe(post);
    },
    [isFetchingNextPage, fetchNextPage, hasNextPage],
  );

  if (status === 'error') return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
  const content = data?.pages.map((pg) => {
    return pg.map((post, i) => {
      if (pg.length === i + 1) {
        return <ArticleList ref={lastPostRef} article={post} key={post.url} />;
      }
      return <ArticleList article={post} key={post.url} />;
    });
  });

  return (
    <div className="feed-container">
      {content}
      {isFetchingNextPage && <p>Loading more posts...</p>}
    </div>
  );
};
```

I also keep the articles-loading part inside their own context.

I'm fairly new to React and currently need to implement infinite scrolling. It's working, however, every time new content is loaded the whole Feed component re-renders because of the way pageNum is updated.

I'm using an Intersection Observer. Every time the scroll reaches the bottom of the page I use a custom hook to make a call loading 6 more elements.
This is the custom hook:

```
const usePosts = (pageNum = 1) => {
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState({});
  const [hasNextPage, setHasNextPage] = useState(false);
  const { category } = useArticlesContext();

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    setIsError(false);
    setError({});

    const controller = new AbortController();
    const { signal } = controller;
    getPostsPageArticles(category, pageNum, { signal })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        setResults((prev) => [...prev, ...data]);
        setHasNextPage(Boolean(data.length));
        setIsLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        setIsLoading(false);
        if (signal.aborted) return;
        setIsError(true);
        setError({ message: e.message });
      });

    return () => controller.abort();
  }, [pageNum, category]);
  useEffect(() => {
    setResults([]);
  }, [category]);

  return { isLoading, isError, error, results, hasNextPage };
};
```

And this is the component in question:

```
const Feed = () => {
  const [pageNum, setPageNum] = useState(1);

  const { isLoading, isError, error, results, hasNextPage } = usePosts(pageNum);
  const intObserver = useRef();

  const lastPostRef = useCallback(
    (post) => {
      if (isLoading) return;
      if (intObserver.current) intObserver.current.disconnect();

      intObserver.current = new IntersectionObserver((posts) => {
        if (posts[0].isIntersecting && hasNextPage) {
          console.log('We are near the last post');
          setPageNum((prev) => prev + 1);
        }
      });

      if (post) intObserver.current.observe(post);
    },
    [isLoading, hasNextPage],
  );

  if (isLoading) return <div>Loading...</div>;

  if (isError) return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;

  const content = results.map((post, i) => {
    if (results.length === i + 1) {
      return <ArticleCard ref={lastPostRef} article={post} />;
    }
    return <ArticleCard article={post} />;
  });

  return (
    <div className="feed-container">
      {content}
      {isLoading && <p>Loading more posts...</p>}
    </div>
  );
};
```

The ArticleCard component in the `content` variable is this:

```
const ArticleCard = React.forwardRef(({ article }, ref) => {
  const articleCardBody = (
    <>
      <div className="article-card__title">
        <h2>{article.title}</h2>
      </div>

      <img src={article.img} alt="" className="article-card__img" />

      <div className="article-card__content">
        <p>{article.content}</p>
      </div>
    </>
  );

  const content = ref ? (
    <div className="article-card" ref={ref}>
      {articleCardBody}
    </div>
  ) : (
    <div className="article-card">{articleCardBody}</div>
  );
  return content;
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated, I'm losing my mind. How could I prevent this behaviour?

Thank you.